# Hello, trying to create an illustration of memory-barriers, in c#

Tags: c#, volatile, memory-barriers

I took upon myself to present my team with a situation where a bug would be introduced by the rearrangement of instructions, however my understanding of CPUs, CLR, and JIT is quite amateurish and I did not manage to pull off a good example.

Below I show what is the best I came up with, so please look at the code snippet to understand what I am talking about from here on.

The main point is in thread2's *if statement*, if it ever happens - it means that the instructions were rearranged. if i manually rearrange the instructions in thread 1 or in thread 2 -> the printing will happened(even if you you swap c.x and c.y reads in thread 2, it will print due to a race condition).

My idea was to force a rearrangement of writes of x and z by making the variables which are placed farther apart integers thinking it could write them both withing one cpu cycle due to the 8 byte word size, instead of it being 3 cycles of writing 4 -> 8 -> 4 bytes. (I know it is not actually 3 cpu cycles, unfortunately, I don't know anything about assembly.) I even tried as a last resort to put it in a struct, thinking that would force some kind of an optimization from JIT.

Any help would be appreciated, because I am very eager to make it work. (I have also tried to follow the examples shown in the ebook by Joseph Albahari, but those did not work, this is why i tried to make a more sophisticated example.) I also did not forget compiling in Release for x64 instruction set.

Code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            var delegates = new MultiTreadingDelegates(i);

            Task.Run(delegates.Thread1);
            Task.Run(delegates.Thread2);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MultiTreadingDelegates
{
    private int i = 0;

    private Container container = new Container();

    public MultiTreadingDelegates(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void Thread1()
    {
        container.X = 10000000;
        container.Z = 6000000000;
        container.Y = 20000000;
    }

    public void Thread2()
    {
        int y = container.Y;
        long z = container.Z;
        int x = container.X;

        if (x != 0 && z == 0 && y != 0)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"i = {i}{Environment.NewLine}"
                                     + $"x = {x}{Environment.NewLine}"
                                     + $"z = {z}{Environment.NewLine}"
                                     + $"y = {y}{Environment.NewLine}"
                                     );
        }
    }
}

public struct Container
{
    public int X;
    public long Z;
    public int Y;
}
```

Comment: Try watching [this](https://youtu.be/6wZVpg2SyJQ) amazing (in my opinion) talk by Sasha Goldshtein. One of the examples he uses is to run some C# code on ARM device (phone, for example).

Comment: One of the troubles with concurrency-related bugs is that the code often runs perfectly many times before the bug actually manifests itself. Another issue is that while memory barriers are still important on x86/x64 architectures, the CPU's memory model itself already impose volatile semantics on reads and writes, so issues are harder to reproduce (you need to get the compiler to reorder things, because CPU reordering only happens safely). Unfortunately, "how to reliably get this concurrent code to fail?" is really too broad, as many variables are involved.

Comment: As far as the code you posted goes, besides the x86/x64 issue, there is also the fact that you loop outside the threads, and you use `Console.WriteLine()` in the thread, both of which impose memory barriers. These shouldn't affect the ordering of instructions in the threads directly, but it creates some correlation that may affect it and reduce the likelihood of seeing a problem. You might see a better demonstration if you use `static` variables and independent threads each with their own loop. And of course, don't use an x86/x64 CPU for the demo.

Comment: I thank you all for the answers, I will for sure watch the video.

I know the writes might create issues some times, but i put them only only before/after the variable are read/written. I did try a different a bit more complex example where threads are running in their own loops and "fire each other" with a semaphore after the situation is reset, but that did not work as well. I am not sure if the variables were static there or not, they could be though.

I hoped to introduce the reordering during the JIT compilation, as i know that the C# compiler, has more strict rules about reordering.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Is C# `volatile` really just acquire / release, not seq_cst (in C++11 terms)?  x86's memory model for normal loads and stores is program-order + a store buffer with store forwarding.  That allows StoreLoad reordering, not sequential consistency.  (And other possibly-surprising effects when a core reloads its own stores.)  Or are you only talking about x86 atomic RMW operations like `lock add [rdi], eax`?  Yes, those are only available as part of a full barrier, not relaxed.

Comment: @PeterC: for better or worse, C#'s `volatile` is overloaded, affecting both compiler output and runtime behavior. I'm the wrong person to provide detailed information; there's a lot of hand-waving behind my earlier comment, it's only intended to provide the gist. Anyone who wants detailed, accurate information would want to look at both the C# language spec and the CLS to fully understand what guarantees `volatile` does and does not provide. That said, the memory model as described by those specs is more formalized, and so won't have the nuances you'll find in actual hardware implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the lecture of Sasha Goldshtein - a video i was given as a comment to my question - I have managed to pull off and example of reordering on an Intel machine(code below)! I thank everyone once again for their help.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(DelegatesUsingPetersons.Thread1);
        Task.Run(DelegatesUsingPetersons.Thread2).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}

static class DelegatesUsingPetersons
{
    private static long x = 0;
    private static long y = 0;
    private static bool flag1 = false;
    private static bool flag2 = false;

    public static void Thread1()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            flag1 = true;
            /*Thread.MemoryBarrier();*/  //Uncomment to fix locking mechanism
            if (flag2 == false)
            {
                x++;
                y++;
            }
            flag1 = false;
        }
    }

    public static void Thread2()
    {
        long lx = 0;
        long ly = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            flag2 = true;
            /*Thread.MemoryBarrier();*/  //Uncomment to fix locking mechanism
            if (flag1 == false)
            {
                lx = x;
                ly = y;
            }
            flag2 = false;

            if (lx != ly)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"lx={lx}, ly={ly} - OMG this cannot happen!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to juxtapose it with a working "more traditional" code, here is the same kind of code just without Mr.Peterson doing all the fancy algorithmic witchcraft

```
static class DelegatesUsingLock
{
    private static long x = 0;
    private static long y = 0;
    private static object loq = new object();

    public static void Thread1()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(loq))
            {
                x++;
                y++;
                Monitor.Exit(loq);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Thread2()
    {
        long lx = 0;
        long ly = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(loq))
            {
                lx = x;
                ly = y;
                Monitor.Exit(loq);
            }

            if (lx != ly)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"lx={lx}, ly={ly} - This Never Happens");
            }
        }
    }
}
```