# Are all C# writes 'volatile'?

Tags: c#, memory, volatile, memory-model

I'm studying c# memory model for concurrent programming.
The MSDN has an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice) regarding C# memory model.
It explains that `volatile write` has [release semantic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/acquire-and-release-semantics), that is,

> other processors will see every preceding operation's effect before the effect of the operation itself.

According to this, any memory operations prior to `volatile write` can't be reordered past the `volatile write`. And this makes it possible for a lock-free publication of memory change.

But I came across [this blog post from 2010](http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/) which states that

> in C# all writes are volatile (unlike say in Java), regardless of whether you write to a volatile or a non-volatile field.

And I think he has a point, thinking that two threads writing on a non-volatile field do update memory right after its execution finishes(even though a race condition may occur), rather than keeping that value to cache of their own.

But does that mean that every write operation on C# has release semantic?

Comment: "in C# all writes are volatile" That's patently and provably not true, you need a memory barrier to get release semantic, and you need some kind of interlocking to force the write back to main memory anyway

Comment: @Charlieface *"That's patently and provably not true"* -- I would be very interested to see a proof that writes in C# are not volatile! Is it provable on any machine, or it requires specific hardware?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cbrumme/memory-model "Memory Model by Chris Brumme") old article by Chris Brumme might be helpful though. Quote: *"In my opinion, we screwed up when we specified the ECMA memory model. That model is unreasonable because: [...] These mistakes cannot be discovered through testing, because the hardware is too strong."*

Comment: @TheodorZoulias https://stackoverflow.com/a/62172885/14868997 and https://dotnetfiddle.net/t9gvFv I think that article is somewhat out of date, and also there are weaker hardware models out there, as he points out.

Comment: @Charlieface [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t9gvFv) example includes both reads and writes. It only proves that either reads are not volatile, or writes are not volatile, or both are not volatile. To prove that **writes** in C# are not volatile, you should make sure that all reads in the example are volatile, by replacing `if (flag2 == false)` with `if (Volatile.Read(ref flag2) == false)` etc.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your comments!
@TheodorZoulias I read the article you mentioned. In the middle the author also says that
> All stores are actually store.release
but assumes that the code runs on x86 architecture.

Now I see that the actual memory model implementation may differ with respect to CPU architectures. Maybe I'll have to be more cautious when using volatile keyword in c#.